# Vue file test coverage not showing in VueJS & Mocha project

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, vuejs3

I tried creating a new fresh VueJS project with the configuration below.

```
vue create vue-unit-test
Please pick a preset: My Project ([Vue 3] dart-sass, babel, typescript, pwa, router, vuex, eslint, unit-mocha, e2e
-cypress)
```

I wanted to show the coverage for `@/components/HelloWorld.vue` from the initial Unit test `example.spec.ts` in the fresh install.

I tried adding several libraries `nyc`, `instanbul`, `babel-plugin-istanbul`, `cross-env`.  After that I added several configurations.

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
        ['istanbul'],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

```
//nyc.config.js
module.exports = {
  'check-coverage': false,
  'per-file': true,
  'skip-full': true,
  all: true,
  include: ['src/**/*.{js,vue}'],
  exclude: [
    'src/*.js',
    '**/index.js',
    'src/plugins/*',
  ],
  reporter: ['lcov', 'text', 'text-summary'],
  extension: ['.js', '.vue'],
}
```

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
            config.merge({
                target: 'node',
                devtool: 'eval',
            });
        }
   },
};
```

After that I added command in the `package.json`

```
    "test:unit:coverage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

You can see the whole repository here

https://github.com/petrabarus/vue-unit-test

When I tried running the command

```
npm run test:unit:coverage
```

the result is below

```
> vue-unit-test@0.1.0 test:unit:coverage
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc vue-cli-service test:unit

 WEBPACK  Compiling...

  [=========================] 98% (after emitting)

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1142ms

  [=========================] 100% (completed)

 WEBPACK  Compiled successfully in 1142ms

 MOCHA  Testing...



  HelloWorld.vue
    ✓ renders props.msg when passed


  1 passing (16ms)

 MOCHA  Tests completed successfully

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.1.0 -> 8.5.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.5.1 to update!
npm notice
```

There is no Vue file in the coverage. I expect the `@components/HelloWorld.vue` to show in the result.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#typescript-projects

> TypeScript projects
>
> Please start with the pre-configured `@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript` preset.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript

> First install the dependencies:
>
> ```
> npm i -D nyc source-map-support ts-node @istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript
> ```
>
> And write a `.nycrc` that looks like this:
>
> ```
> {
>    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
>    // OPTIONAL if you want coverage reported on every file, including those that aren't tested:
>    "all": true
> }
> ```
>
> In `test/mocha.opts:
>
> ```
> --require ts-node/register #replace with ts-node/register/transpile-only if you have custom types
> --require source-map-support/register
> --recursive
> <glob for your test files>
> ```

Comment: Still not working :(
https://github.com/petrabarus/vue-unit-test/pull/1

Comment: in `nyc.config.js` , replace `.js` to `.ts`.

Comment: Still nothing. It just says `Error: No test files found: "test"`